# Limiting WP user's access to the amount of credits they have

Tags: php, wordpress

I like this solution but maybe there is another way. My goal with this is to limit user editing to the amount of credits they have. What do you think?

Here is what it does:

- Credits are stored as user meta _credits (int).
- Users can only edit pages, posts, custom post types if they have credits left.
- Show a proper message when the user does not have any credits left.
- Admin users should always be allowed to do thing regardless of having credits or not.

The edit post screens is cleared from all editing components and show an error message when the user does not have any credits left.

Here is some sample code I tested with that is working:

```
update_user_meta(get_current_user_id(), '_credits', '0'); //just for testing
add_action('add_meta_boxes', function() {
    global $wp_meta_boxes, $credits;

    //get current user's credits
    $credits = intval(get_user_meta(get_current_user_id(), '_credits', true));

    if(is_admin()) {
        //keep everything as it is, admin can always access everything
    } else
        if($credits > 0) {
        //show how many credits the user have left
        add_action('admin_notices', function() {
            global $credits;
            echo '<div id="message" class="updated fade"><p><strong>You have ' . $credits . ' credit(s).</strong></p></div>';
        });
    } else {
        $post_type = get_current_screen()->id;

        //remove title and editor editing components
        remove_post_type_support($post_type, 'title');
        remove_post_type_support($post_type, 'editor');

        //remove all meta boxes
        foreach($wp_meta_boxes[$post_type] as $context=>$priorities) {
            foreach($priorities as $priority=>$metaboxes) {
                foreach($metaboxes as $metabox=>$metabox_data) {
                    remove_meta_box($metabox, $post_type, $context);
                }
            }
        }

        //show an error message
        add_action('admin_notices', function() {
            echo '<div id="message" class="error"><p><strong>You are out of credit(s). <a href="http://buy/more/link">Buy some more credits</a>.</strong></p></div>';
        });
    }
});
```